# Why does everyone park so far away?

Tags: film-techniques

Seems to be a lot of films & TV shows were people park their car/truck/horse/TARDIS hundreds of metres from their destination for no apparent reason.

This is opposed to those times where there's always a carpark right in front of the door, against all probability.

An example of this is from the film Thor, where the hero and his friends are riding horses along the Bifrost bridge.  About 100 metres from the dome, they stop their horses, dismount, and apparently walk the rest of the way.  The horses, presumably mystical, aren't seen again.

[image: we could park next to the door, but that's boring]

You can see this in action here:

Is there a particular reason for this?  Is it a deliberate thing, or is it just a Trope?

Comment: Perhaps you could include a few examples? I'm not really sure what you are asking.

Comment: I was always under impression that it's exactly [the opposite](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/RockStarParking).

Comment: You _obviously_ have never seen Clark W. Griswold "park" a car :P

Comment: @ChanandlerBong - I'm well aware of Rockstar Parking.  I'm asking about the opposite - parking miles away even when it's not necessary.

Comment: Exposition, showoff, wide shots from the places they are about to go?

Comment: Agreed with Gustavo. This is a shortcut to get more information into a scene with fewer shots/cuts.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### It shows off the visuals, and allows the possibility of a 'Walk and Talk'

Taken from the TV Tropes page, a  [Walk and Talk](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WalkAndTalk) is:

> **Having the characters walk from one end to the other of a large, contiguous set while talking to each other**, while a SteadiCam operator walks backwards in front of them, allowing for a continuous, moving, Medium Two Shot. Can take a lot of takes to get right, but can give us some impressive examples of The Oner. However, they never seem to watch where they're going.

As @Gustavo says, you can have your characters park far away if you need to fill the travelling time with exposition (in a way that is visually appealing). Or it can be used just to emphasise the location.

A good example of this in action is in the *Doctor Who* episode, New Earth.

In the opening scene, the Doctor lands the TARDIS well away from the hospital he's been summoned to, which gives Rose (and us) plenty of time to take in the scenery and the necessary exposition.